# POSGTRESQL 9.10 - returning the maximum value from a JSON arrays

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

Looking for a method to calculate the maximum value is an numeric arrays contained in a json array using postgresql.

Simple example:

```
room, data
1   , '{"history":{"samples":{"101":[5,10,50,20],"102":[10,15,5,5]}}}'
```

What I'm looking for is the maximum value for a particular "history -> sample" item for a room.  This this case, it would be "50" for sample 101 and "15" for sample 102 but the real data is larger than this.

Here is sqlfiddle to some actual data.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c7a0

Ultimately, I would like to end up with a pivot with the room and samples as columns with the maximum value in that array.  Is there a fairly simple way to do this with the large number of elements in the arrays?  (crosstab or cross lateral join?)  Something like the following based on the simple example from above:

```
room | 101 | 102 | ... ->
1    |  50 |  15
2    |   x |   x
etc..
..
```

again, see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c7a0) for sample data

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LATERAL` and `json_array_elements`:

```
SELECT j.id, s2.*
FROM jsonData j
,LATERAL (SELECT (data -> 'history') -> 'data' ) s(c)
,LATERAL ( VALUES(
          (SELECT MAX(value::text::decimal(10,2))
          FROM json_array_elements((s.c -> '101')::json) x),
          (SELECT MAX(value::text::decimal(10,2))
          FROM json_array_elements((s.c -> '102')::json) x))
         )s2("101","102");  -- are more cols here
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=2d5affcf34d78f363eba73c2e4c8e3a4)**

Comment: @alfasin Yes I am. Column names should be known in advance.

Comment: It's not column names, it's keys inside a JSONB column. And the OP explicitly wrote: "but the real data is larger than this". Can you grab these keys dynamically?

Comment: @alfasin Even if, the subquery has to return specific columns(you cannot make it dynamically at least not without some mechanism like PTF/dynamic SQL/crosstab with subselect).

Comment: Thanks very much!

Dynamically would be nice touch but this is much farther than I've gotten so this helps emensly.  I've seen some nice PL function like http://www.cureffi.org/2013/03/19/automatically-creating-pivot-table-column-names-in-postgresql/   that do a very nice job.  Maybe we able incorporate this at sometime.  Better yet - maybe PostgreSQL code managers will implement something like this for everyone! :)

Comment: Not to complicate this - but how would you approach taking a sub-group of the array?  For example we want the maximum value starting at the nth element for x elements in the array?  The exact starting point and number is dynamic based on other data....

Comment: @Kip I think this should be another question with sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but it may help getting you close to what you're looking for:

```
select key, data->'history'->'data' #> array[key] as values
from
(select *, jsonb_object_keys(data->'history'->'data') as key
from jsonData) as a
```

Output:

[image]

See [fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c7a0/67)

You can select only a single room and do all the work on it, then it's easier:

```
select key, max(val::text::float) from
(
select key, jsonb_array_elements(values) as val
from
(select key, data->'history'->'data' #> array[key] as values
from
(select *, jsonb_object_keys(data->'history'->'data') as key
from jsonData) as a) 
  as b
  ) as c
group by key
order by 1
```

[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2c7a0/92)

output:

[image]

And if you want to display it in horizontal way instead of vertical, you can use [crosstab (tablefunc)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html)